# Rust function which takes function with arg a function

Tags: rust, function-pointers

I want to write a generic function `count_calls` which calls a function `f` which takes a function pointer (lambda) where `count_calls` counts how often function `f` called the given lambda function.

I struggle with the approach ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=391121e5ac23c0451db939809e51b342)).

```rust
fn count_calls<S, F>(s: S, f: F) -> u32
where
    S: Clone,
    F: Sized + FnMut(Fn() -> S) -> (),
{
    let mut counter: u32 = 0;

    f(|| {
        counter += 1;
        s.clone()
    });
    counter
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod stackoverflow {
    use super::*;

    fn f(p: fn() -> i32) {
        p();
        p();
    }

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let counts = count_calls(3, f);
        assert_eq!(counts, 2);
    }
}
```

Here I get the error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::ops::Fn() -> S + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/lib.rs:1:1
   |
1  | / fn count_calls<S, F>(s: S, f: F) -> u32
2  | | where
3  | |     S: Clone,
4  | |     F: Sized + FnMut(Fn() -> S) -> (),
...  |
12 | |     counter
13 | | }
   | |_^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: within `((dyn std::ops::Fn() -> S + 'static),)`, the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::ops::Fn() -> S + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: required because it appears within the type `((dyn std::ops::Fn() -> S + 'static),)`
   = note: required by `std::ops::FnMut`
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

**[Edit]**

I think using `Box<Fn()->S>` might be a solution. But I would prefer a stack only solution, if possible.

Comment: this is tougher than I thought it would be because of the anonymous closure type that gets passed to `f`... I'm excited to see how the rust experts handle this

Comment: Just to be sure: is this a purely theoretical question (just for fun/out of interest) or is there an actual problem you want to solve? If the latter is the case, maybe you want to share a bit of detail about that problem. But a purely theoretical question is fine, too, of course! In fact, this is a good question IMO. I'm puzzled (although I don't think it's possible with static dispatch yet :/).

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt This is the simplified version of an actual problem, which points out the key problem. The actual problem is a kind of `map` or `flat_map`. But the mapping function takes a function pointer which allows it to request additional data. The map provides by this the items of an array (only one for each request). If there were data requested and all items are provided by the map, the map feeds the next item of the prev iterator. You can see it as a cross join from SQL. But computing the array is costly and only rarely needed. That's why it is done lazy by function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest code that I managed to get working ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4863f16ff0d49d117f4ffa3b90768812)):

```
fn count_calls<S, F>(s: S, mut f: F) -> u32
where
    S: Clone,
    F: FnMut(&mut dyn FnMut() -> S) -> (),
{
    let mut counter: u32 = 0;

    f(&mut || {
        counter += 1;
        s.clone()
    });
    counter
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod stackoverflow {
    use super::*;

    fn f(p: &mut dyn FnMut() -> i32) {
        p();
        p();
    }

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let counts = count_calls(3, f);
        assert_eq!(counts, 2);
    }
}
```

The key change is that the function argument for `F` is changed from `Fn() -> S` into `&mut dyn FnMut() -> S`. You need a reference because you are using dynamic dispatching. Also you need `FnMut` because you are capturing `counter` and changing it inside, and a `Fn` will not allow it.

Note that you cannot use `Box<FnMut() -> S`. It will not allow capturing a reference to `counter` because boxed functions must be `'static`.

If you find that changing your `Fn` to `FnMut` is undesirable (because you are changing your public API) you could go back to `F: FnMut(&mut dyn Fn() -> S) -> ()` by defining counter as a `Cell<u32>`:

```
fn count_calls<S, F>(s: S, mut f: F) -> u32
where
    S: Clone,
    F: FnMut(&dyn Fn() -> S) -> (),
{
    let counter: Cell<u32> = Cell::new(0);

    f(&|| {
        counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
        s.clone()
    });
    counter.into_inner()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The error "*the size for values of type `(dyn std::ops::Fn() -> S + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time*" is caused by your trait bound for `F`:

```
F: Sized + FnMut(Fn() -> S) -> ()
```

This is equivalent to `F: Sized + FnMut(dyn Fn() -> S)`. This means that the closure `F` would take a trait object (`dyn Fn() -> S`) by value. But trait objects are unsized and cannot be passed by value (yet).

One solution would be to pass the trait object by reference or in a `Box`. [The answer by rodrigo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55753483/2408867) explains and discusses these solutions.

---

### Can we avoid trait objects and dynamic dispatch?

Not properly, I think.

#### Non solutions

One idea would be to add another type parameter to `count_calls`:

```
fn count_calls<S, F, G>(s: S, f: F) -> u32
where
    S: Clone,
    F: Sized + FnMut(G),
    G: Fn() -> S,
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:9:7
   |
9  |       f(|| {
   |  _______^
10 | |         counter += 1;
11 | |         s.clone()
12 | |     });
   | |_____^ expected type parameter, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `G`
              found type `[closure@src/lib.rs:9:7: 12:6 counter:_, s:_]`
```

The problem here is that type arguments of `count_calls` are chosen by the caller of `count_calls`. But we actually want `G` to always be the type of our own closure. So that doesn't work.

What we want is a generic closure (where *we* can choose it's type parameters). Something similar is possible, but restricted to lifetime parameters. It's called HRTBs and looks like `F: for<'a> Fn(&'a u32)`. But it doesn't help here because we need a type parameter and `for<T>` doesn't exist (yet?).

#### Sub-optimal, nightly solution

One solution would be to not use a closure, but a type with a known name which implements `FnMut`. Sadly, you can't implement the `Fn*` traits for your own type on stable yet. [On nightly, this works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c5ef6fc0189b345385ce87c52ecb15b6).

```
struct CallCounter<S> {
    counter: u32,
    s: S,
}
impl<S: Clone> FnOnce<()> for CallCounter<S> {
    type Output = S;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _: ()) -> Self::Output {
        // No point in incrementing the counter here
        self.s
    }
}
impl<S: Clone> FnMut<()> for CallCounter<S> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, _: ()) -> Self::Output {
        self.counter += 1;
        self.s.clone()
    }
}

fn count_calls<S, F>(s: S, mut f: F) -> u32
where
    S: Clone,
    F: Sized + FnMut(&mut CallCounter<S>),     // <----
{
    let mut counter = CallCounter {
        counter: 0,
        s,
    };

    f(&mut counter);   // <-------

    counter.counter
}
```

Unfortunately, now you have this strange type in your public interface (which should be implementation detail).

---

Apart from that, I can't think of any real solution (only other super verbose solutions with plenty of disadvantages). The developments in the type system corner (in particular in regards to GATs and HKTs) could solve this properly in the future. However, I think there are still a few different features lacking; in particular, I don't think that GATs as proposed would already solve this.

So if this is a real life problem which needs to be solved right now, I would:

- step back and rethink the problem in a bigger scope to maybe avoid this Rust limitation, or
- just use dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Great answer! But I think that in this case dynamic dispatching is simply the best solution. It is not such a performance loss that it is worth writing convoluted code just to avoid it.